# jenkins in docker - how to change timezone

Tags: docker, jenkins

Question:

- How do I set the timezone in jenkins in a docker container so that when you reboot the server it retains the setting?

So i'm running RHEL 7 on AWS with docker and jenkins (https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkinsci/blueocean/).

This article talks about how to change the timezone
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Change+time+zone

essentially two ways

1. run System.setProperty('org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone', 'America/New_York') in the script console which works but if you reboot the server or jenkins it reverts back
2. add it to /etc/sysconfig/jenkins, unfortunately that directory does not exist as it's running in a container

However i have created a volume for the settings folder this way

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -v $PWD/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home:z -t jenkinsci/blueocean
```

this makes the home directory "jenkins-blue"

the directory listing is

```
4 -rw-r--r--.   1 <omitted user>  1647 Feb 27 17:00 config.xml
4 -rw-r--r--.   1 <omitted user>  3982 Feb 27 16:57 copy_reference_file.log
4 -rw-r--r--.   1 <omitted user>   966 Feb 27 17:04 credentials.xml
0 drwxr-xr-x.   3 <omitted user>    16 Feb 27 17:06 fingerprints
4 -rw-r--r--.   1 <omitted user>   156 Feb 27 16:57 hudson.model.UpdateCenter.xml
4 -rw-r--r--.   1 <omitted user>  1230 Feb 27 17:07 hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.xml
4 -rw-r--r--.   1 <omitted user>   370 Feb 27 16:58 hudson.plugins.git.GitTool.xml
4 -rw-------.   1 <omitted user>  1712 Feb 27 16:57 identity.key.enc
0 drwxr-xr-x.   2 <omitted user>    41 Feb 27 16:57 init.groovy.d
4 -rw-r--r--.   1 <omitted user>    94 Feb 27 16:58 jenkins.CLI.xml
4 -rw-r--r--.   1 <omitted user>     7 Feb 27 17:00 jenkins.install.InstallUtil.lastExecVersion
4 -rw-r--r--.   1 <omitted user>     7 Feb 27 17:00 jenkins.install.UpgradeWizard.state
4 -rw-r--r--.   1 <omitted user>   183 Feb 27 17:00 jenkins.model.JenkinsLocationConfiguration.xml
4 -rw-r--r--.   1 <omitted user>   171 Feb 27 16:57 jenkins.telemetry.Correlator.xml
0 drwxr-xr-x.   3 <omitted user>    18 Feb 27 17:00 jobs
0 drwxr-xr-x.   4 <omitted user>    37 Feb 27 16:58 logs
4 -rw-r--r--.   1 <omitted user>   907 Feb 27 16:58 nodeMonitors.xml
0 drwxr-xr-x.   2 <omitted user>     6 Feb 27 16:58 nodes
20 drwxr-xr-x. 106 <omitted user> 16384 Feb 27 16:59 plugins
4 -rw-r--r--.   1 <omitted user>   129 Feb 28 17:35 queue.xml
4 -rw-r--r--.   1 <omitted user>    64 Feb 27 16:57 secret.key
0 -rw-r--r--.   1 <omitted user>     0 Feb 27 16:57 secret.key.not-so-secret
4 drwx------.   4 <omitted user>  4096 Feb 27 17:14 secrets
0 drwxr-xr-x.   2 <omitted user>   182 Feb 27 16:59 updates
0 drwxr-xr-x.   2 <omitted user>    24 Feb 27 16:58 userContent
0 drwxr-xr-x.   3 <omitted user>    57 Feb 27 17:00 users
4 drwxr-xr-x.  11 <omitted user>  4096 Feb 27 16:57 war
0 drwxr-xr-x.   2 <omitted user>     6 Feb 27 16:58 workflow-libs
0 drwxr-xr-x.   4 <omitted user>    34 Feb 27 17:06 workspace
```

Answer (score 17):

You may apply a **TZ** environment into your docker-compose like this:

```
image: jenkins/jenkins:alpine
container_name: jenkins
hostname: jenkins
restart: always
environment:
  - TZ=Asia/Shanghai
volumes:
  - ./jenkins/data:/var/jenkins_home
  - ./jenkins/bin/jenkins.war:/usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
```

Comment: and without docker compose just add `-e TZ=Asia/Shanghai`

Comment: This works when using the jenkins classic UI to view log files with time stamp lines.  However, it fails when viewing the same log files using the blueocean UI.  I guess blueocean doesn't honor TZ?

Answer (score 6):

Run it in `System Management -> Script command line`：

```
System.setProperty('org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone', 
'Asia/Shanghai')
```

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Change+time+zone

BTW, I add this in my Timed tasks:

```
TZ=Asia/Shanghai
40 15 * * 1-5
```

OR

```
docker run ... -e JAVA_OPTS=-Duser.timezone=Asia/Shanghai
```

https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/issues/45

Answer (score 4):

### Dockerfile

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.176.1

USER root

# Configure Timezone
RUN \
rm -f /etc/localtime && \
ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles /etc/localtime && \
echo 'America/Los_Angeles' > /etc/timezone && \
dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
```

Comment: This worked for me! Do necessarily need the `echo 'America/Los_Angeles' > /etc/timezone`?

Answer (score 0):

Simply Map the volume while running jenkins container

-v /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro

Answer (score 0):

environment:

- TZ=Asia/Shanghai
  This work for me

Answer (score 0):

I could set the Time Zone from Jenkins and the Docker container, by adding the following in the Dockerfile:

> ENV TZ=America/Los_Angeles
> ...
> RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone